# Retrieving emails and storing them in MySQL

Tags: mysql, email, imap, crm, pop3

How would one retrieve emails from an email server and put them into a mysql database?

Idealistically sticking with php. But could incorporate another language if needed.

Comment: question is not clear dear . please elaborate  it more dear/

Comment: Basically, how would I retrieve emails from my email server into a mysql database?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there's.

If you're using a hosting solution with cPanel. You should take a look at

http://www.webmasters-central.com/article-blog/tutorials/email-pipe-tutorial-setting-up-email-piping/

http://devtrench.com/posts/simple-email-logger-using-cpanels-pipe-forwarder

(useful for php scripts)

If you're using a Postfix solution take a look at

https://serverfault.com/questions/258469/how-to-configure-postfix-to-pipe-all-incoming-email-to-a-script

http://evolt.org/incoming_mail_and_php?from=50

You should look for "piping email to php" or "piping email to python" or what the language you're using on google.

Anyway, with PHP or Python you can achieve that, getting your incoming email to a DB.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the whole class which can help you do this i have used it and its working

http://www.phpclasses.org/package/3324-PHP-Retrieve-e-mail-messages-into-a-MySQL-database.html

further you can get help from
[PHP email to mysql database issue when not deleting emails from server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14669177/php-email-to-mysql-database-issue-when-not-deleting-emails-from-server)

see the code he used, its is done by imap_open also see this

http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-open.php

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Comment: thanks dear kleopatra i will take care of this suggestion next time

Comment: Unfortunately without fixing this answer (per kleopatra's suggestion) the links alone arent useful and require further registration/login at other websites to even test if the answer is accurate.