# PHP email to mysql database issue when not deleting emails from server

Tags: php, mysql, imap, pop3

I am using a php class etodb found here

http://www.phpclasses.org/package/3324-PHP-Retrieve-e-mail-messages-into-a-MySQL-database.html

It checks an email account and downloads the messages into a mysql database.  It works perfectly, however at the end of each loop (looping for each message in the inbox) it deletes the email.  I know how to stop it from deleting the email, but the issue is for some reason the script wont insert any new emails into the database unless I allow it to delete the messages OR the inbox is completely empty.

Here is the end portion of the php class referenced above.  This section just loops through each message and inserts it into the database AND if set it will delete the messages.  My question in summary is to just let the script work correctly without the need to delete messages or have an empty inbox.

```
$total_messages = $this->num_message(); 

// IM ASSUMING THIS FOR LOOP IS NOT LOOPING MESSAGES CORRECTLY 
for ($i = 0; $i < $total_messages; $i++) {


#Get first message
$email = $this->email_get();

$ismsgdb = $this->db_add_message($email); // THIS INSERTS EACH MSG INTO DATABASE

#Get store dir
$dir = $this->dir_name();

$id_log = $this->add_db_log($email, 'Copy e-mail - start ');

foreach($this->partsarray as $part){
 if($part[text][type] == 'HTML'){
   #$message_HTML = $part[text][string];
   $this->db_update_message($part[text][string], $type= 'HTML');
 }elseif($part[text][type] == 'PLAIN'){
   $message_PLAIN = $part[text][string];
   $this->db_update_message($part[text][string], $type= 'PLAIN');
 }elseif($part[attachment]){
    #Save files(attachments) on local disc

   // $message_ATTACH[] = $part[attachment];
    foreach(array($part[attachment]) as $attach){
        $attach[filename] = $this->mimie_text_decode($attach[filename]);
        $attach[filename] = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9_\-\.]/i', '_', $attach[filename]);
        $this->add_db_log($email, 'Start coping file:"'.strip_tags($attach[filename]).'"');

        $this->save_files($this->newid.$attach[filename], $attach[string]);
        $filename =  $dir.$this->newid.$attach[filename];
        $this->db_add_attach($attach[filename], $filename);
        $this->update_db_log('<b>'.$filename.'</b>Finish coping: "'.strip_tags($attach[filename]).'"', $this->logid);
    }
  //

 }elseif($part[image]){
    #Save files(attachments) on local disc

    $message_IMAGE[] = $part[image];

    foreach($message_IMAGE as $image){
        $image[filename] = $this->mimie_text_decode($image[filename]);
        $image[filename] = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9_\-\.]/i', '_', $image[filename]);
        $this->add_db_log($email, 'Start coping file: "'.strip_tags($image[filename]).'"');


        $this->save_files($this->newid.$image[filename], $image[string]);
        $filename =  $dir.$this->newid.$image[filename];
        $this->db_add_attach($image[filename], $filename);
        $this->update_db_log('<b>'.$filename.'</b>Finish coping:"'.strip_tags($image[filename]).'"', $this->logid);
    }

 }

}
$this->spam_detect();
$this->email_setflag(); 
$this->email_delete(); // WHEN I REMOVE THIS THE SCRIPT WONT GRAB NEW EMAILS
$this->email_expunge(); // WHEN I REMOVE THIS THE SCRIPT WONT GRAB NEW EMAILS




$this->update_db_log('Finish coping', $id_log);


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But your problem is that in the loop, you keep grabbing hte first email.

```
#Get first message
$email = $this->email_get();
```

The class has an internal pointer "$this->msgid" that you need to increment to get the next message. If you set this to $i + 1 before calling the function you should get the next message.

```
#Get message determined b $i
$this->msgeid = $i + 1;
$email = $this->email_get();
```

(Note: edited, now seen the source)

Comment: Thanks!  I knew it was something simple - your solution solved my problem.